# JQuery, hide() not working but remove() is

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using JQuery UI tabs and I'm trying to hide the corresponding tab and div when they click the 'X' on the tab. It is hiding the tab properly; however for some reason it does not hide the div.

```
function hideTab(element){
  $(element).parent().hide();
  $($(element).parent().attr('href')).hide() // hide() is not working on this line
}
```

Does anybody know why this is? Here is the codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eaLmNg

Thanks!